# How to add UIButtons to navigationbar ,the class also consists UITabbarController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new at iOS Development.I Have `UINavigationController` as rootviewcontroller for `UIWindow`.In the subclass i added `UITabbarController` programatically.I given default Tabbarcontroller selection as first controller. Here i am trying to add 3 buttons to the navigationbar .

Can any send me the corrent code.
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple code for add `UIButton` on `UINavigationBar`

In Following code you can add Button With **`FlexibleSpace`**

```
NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];
    [flexSpace release];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnFirst = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(FirstTapped:)];
    [barItems addObject: btnFirst];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnSecond = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(SecondTapped:)];
    [barItems addObject:btnSecond];

UIBarButtonItem *btnThird = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Third" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(ThirdTapped:)];
    [barItems addObject: btnThird];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = barItems;
```

**Button Related Methods**

```
-(void) FirstTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{

//perform your action

}
-(void) SecondTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{

//perform your action

}

-(void) ThirdTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{

//perform your action

}
```

**NOTE  :** `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems`  **Works only in iOS 5 or Latter.**

Comment: Shouldn't that be `-(void) FirstButtonTapped
{
   // Code related to function 
}`

?

Answer (score 0):

To add more than one button on the left or the right side you have to call one of the following methods:

```
- (void)setRightBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated

- (void)setLeftBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated
```

The array `items` contains instances of the `UIBarButtonItem` class. You can instantiate them like this

```
UIBarButtonItem *FirstButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                       initWithTitle:@"Title"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                              target:self 
                              action:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
```

Then you have to implement the selector `buttonTapped:` which is called when the button has been tapped.

```
-(void)buttonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
{
  // do the things that should happen when the button is pressed
}
```

If you don't want to get them on the left or right side it is also possible to create a `UIView` by yourself containing the buttons and set the view to be the titleView of the `UINavigationItem`. This effect is similar to the buttons in the Facebook App

```
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:yourView];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

// here is custom button setup //

UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:item animated:YES];
```